# sharepoint 2010 popup window

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint-2010, popup

Have some troubles with calling js from code behind.
This is my js code

```
 function showDialog() {
            var options = {
                url: 'DialogWindow.aspx',
                width: 600,
                height: 200,
                title: 'Test',
                showClose: true,
                dialogReturnValueCallback: dialogReturned
            };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        }
        function dialogReturned(dialogResult, returnValue) {
            if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) alert("OK");
            else alert("CANCEL");
        }
```

And this is my c# code to call js function

```
if (!WriteDataToSm())
            {
               //Error Handling
                string script = "<script language='javascript'>showDialog()</script>";
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Register", script);
            }
```

but i'm getting a js error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hiddenButtonValueBeforeDialog' of undefined
```

but when i'm create a button and call js function showDialog() inside onclick event. Everything works fine. pls advide what could be the reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this line of code to execute javascript from code behind:

```
page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "idicosNotify", "$(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(\"" + message + "\", false); }, \"sp.js\"); });", true);
```

When you can call your javascript function with a button then there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I solve my problem with setTimeout function, but I will check your version too. thanks